# Unable to query root folder for changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

MS Graph Explorer - query for OneDrive Business Account is failing

-More info found on the following github issue: 
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1099

-Contacted Office 365 support who referred me here. Microsoft support case: 15301860

MS Graph explorer query:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!a-oNn_Mnm02gMc86rSUI27vOcAGlo8BAhT7CxagLgF2oTC6OgbRmSaXoOirrlVDs/items/01ICHZFV56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ

Expected Behavior:

The item query should return objects.

Actual Behavior:

OneDrive responds with a 404 error - when it should return with valid data that exists.

Comment: If you browse to https://{your-tenant-name}.sharepoint.com does that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't, navigating to https://{my-tenant-name}.sharepoint.com returns 404 FILE NOT FOUND. Maybe this also helps further with troubleshooting; navigating to https://{my-tenant-name}-my.sharepoint.com does work

Comment: Further investigation reveals a deleted sharepoint team site. It's currently in the process of being restored, will report back soon.

Answer (score 0):

When Graph makes a call to SharePoint to fulfill a `/v1.0/drives` request it hits the tenant host, where as it will hit the personal site host for `/v1.0/me/drive`. As a result of this, the `/v1.0/drives` scenario can fail if the tenant's root site is inaccessible which looks like what you're seeing.

I will mention that we're investigating improving this experience, so hopefully in the future you won't hit a failure for this scenario.